# Map is not correctly deserialized in NGXS and cannot be used

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, immutable.js, ngxs

NGXS is used for state management. There are many states that could be implemented as maps to write cleaner code and to improve performance. Currently there is a workaround where the keys are stored in the array as a field and via `findIndex` the arrays can be searched for the key.

When I try to store a map via NGXS, the object is no map after deserialization and I cannot use the map functions like below:

> TypeError: member[index].map.get is not a function

```
@Action(ActionExample)
@ImmutableContext()
public action() {
  const state = getState();
  const entry = state.member[index].map.get(key);
}
```

How can I use maps with NGXS?

Comment: This is clearly state in the style guides of NGXS. You should avoid the use of complex structures that are not easily serializable: https://www.ngxs.io/recipes/style-guide#avoid-saving-class-based-instances-in-your-state